# EJB, JPA/Hibernate. I cannot make an insert in a database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I am using Glassfish, EJB, JPA and Hibernate as a JPA implementation. I can get a select from a database via JPA but an insert does not work. Looks like a problem with JTA(may be a transaction was not completed or I use an another transaction) Persistence content does not flush to a database. The same code works properly when I use eclipselink as JPA implementation but I have to use hibernate.

```
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class BeanISManagedByContainer
    {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.company_JPATest2-ejb_ejb_1.0PU")
        EntityManager entityManager;

        public String getMessage(int id)
        {
            return entityManager.find(Message.class, id).getText();
        }

        public void addMessaage(String txt)
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setText(txt);
            entityManager.persist(message);
        }
    }
```

getMessage() method is works properly, but addMessaage() does not insert any data to a database and there are not any logs. Persistence context was not flushed to a database. I have tried to manage a transaction manually but the same result. I do not know what is wrong with a hibernate configuration. Please advise.

```
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
    public class ManualTransactions
    {
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.company_JPATest2-ejb_ejb_1.0PU")
        EntityManager entityManager;

        @Resource
        private UserTransaction transaction;

        public void addMessaage(String txt) throws Exception
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setText(txt);

            transaction.begin();
            Logger.getLogger(ManualTransactions.class.getName())
                    .info("transaction status: " + transaction.getStatus());
            entityManager.persist(message);
            Logger.getLogger(ManualTransactions.class.getName())
                    .info("transaction status: " + transaction.getStatus());
            transaction.commit();
            Logger.getLogger(ManualTransactions.class.getName())
                    .info("transaction status: " + transaction.getStatus());
        }
    }

**logs:**
Info:   transaction status: 0
Info:   transaction status: 0
Info:   transaction status: 6
```

**persistance.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.company_JPATest2-ejb_ejb_1.0PU" transaction-type="JTA">
 <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
 <jta-data-source>jdbc/JPATestPool</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
 </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pow.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>JPATest2</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>JPATest2-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>JPATest2-ejb</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA EntityManager needs to interact with the container JTA platform in order to get callbacks so that it can flush the context. Depending on the JPA engine it might or might not be able to detect the JTA TransactionManager of the container.

With Hibernate you need to assist it by providing a property which provides the implementation to be used to detect the JTA infrastructure.

Add the following property to the properties section of persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
```

org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform is specific to Glassfish. You have to change accordingly to match the application server you are using

Answer (score 0):

In a container-managed transaction scenario, you need to add @Transactional to the method you expect to commit the transaction.

```
    @Transactional
    public void addMessaage(String txt)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setText(txt);
        entityManager.persist(message);
    }
```